# Google Maps Android API v2 works only on one phone

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, supportmapfragment

I'm working with my team on getting Google Maps to display using their Android API v2.

I managed to get the codes up and tested on **my own phone and it works perfectly**... however when the codes run on my **teammates' phones**, their screens are grey, and they have this:

```
E/Google Maps Android API(30514): Authorization failure.
```

The weird thing is,  this error doesn't appear in their logcat 100%, sometimes they just get the grey screen without any errors. Our codes are sychronized with SVN by the way so they are definitely updated.

My **API key is obtained from the debugging key**, and has been verified to be correct since it runs perfectly on my phone.

I'm not sure what exactly is causing this and thus I'm not sure what codes I can post here to seek help. In the meantime I'm going to post my MapFragment class codes and hope it sheds some light for someone to help.

Please let me know if there's anything else I can post up here to seek an answer and I'll post it asap. Thanks!

```
public class POnlineMapViewFragment extends SherlockMapFragment {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String placeName;
    static Bundle bundle;
    private LatLng point;
    View v;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        bundle = getArguments();
        if(bundle != null) {
        this.latitude = getArguments().getDouble("latitude");
        this.longitude = getArguments().getDouble("longitude");
        this.placeName = getArguments().getString("placeName");
        this.point = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflator, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = super.onCreateView(inflator, container, savedInstanceState);
        mMap = getMap();

        CameraUpdate center= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point);
        CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(placeName).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.gps_small)));


        mMap.moveCamera(center);
        mMap.animateCamera(zoom);

        return v;     

    }

    public static POnlineMapViewFragment newInstance(Bundle b) {
        POnlineMapViewFragment mapfrag = new POnlineMapViewFragment();
        mapfrag.setArguments(b);
        return mapfrag;
    } 
}
```

Comment: your saying, "Google Maps Android API v2 works only on one phone" is right, which is written in the official Development document.

Comment: @BBonDoo sorry what do you mean by that?

Comment: As per i think.Google Maps Android API(30514): Authorization failure means you are not accessing the Google API by using the API key. you have to use google api key and must have gmail account for that.

Comment: @NarendraPal I'm pretty sure the API key is correct as the google map works and displays perfectly on my phone during debugging. It however, does not display on my friends' phone during debugging. Even the Authorization failure doesn't occur 100%, sometimes it will be just a grey screen with no errors whatsoever

Comment: @lyk...please [see this document](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/google/play-services/setup.html).

Comment: @lyk...sorry, I see now..on your friend's phone?...

Comment: @BbonDoo huh??? I'm not sure what I'm supposed to see from the document. the API key and all the required settings has already been done. And yes, I think you might have misunderstood? I'm asking why it doesn't work on my friend's phone running on debugging mode connected to the computer when it does on mine

Comment: @lyk..please check your friend phone's setting is "Enable USB debugging".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the map you need map api key from google,  by providing fingerprint of your keystore cetrificate you used for generating apk (debuge.keystore in case of development environment).
Once you get the map api key for specific certificate you MUST use the same certificate debuge.keystore) to ganerate the apk file to run the app successfully on all the device otherwise it will shows blank map with grey square..

- If you and your friend is generating apk from different machine/pc than you must use same debug certificate to generate the apk file

Comment: Oh, so you're saying that different machines will have different debug keystores? Is that why?

Comment: Its ok.. Locate your debug.keystore file in user/.android directory and replace your friends debug.keystore file with this one, and re-run the app from eclipse.

Comment: I think this is the case with using same installer on emulators of different pcs. Shouldn't be the case with devices

Comment: Is there anything other files I have to pass to my friends? I have asked them to replace the debug.keystore file with and it still doesn't work, still getting the authorization failure which is very weird

Comment: @lyk Plase uninstall the app from emulator or device and reinstall the app.. I should work..

Comment: Still not working even after uninstalling =( I don't know what else I've missed out

Comment: Testing on a fresh phone by passing the phone the .apk file and it works weirdly. Still confused why following the steps of replacing the debug.keystore file in the other computer terminals would not work...

Comment: This is so weird, but after trying half a day later, everything works now! Thank you so much for your help! =)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the solution was to replace my friend's debug.keystore file with my local debug.keystore file on my PC because the key was generated using mine debug.keystore file.